# Connect PivotTables with a Slicer Using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, slicers

I'm working on a dashboard in Excel.

I refactored some pivot tables to allow a single slicer to filter all the graphs, but then discovered that you can't simply change the data source of a pivot table that shares slicers with other tables.

I have a macro which refreshes a table of data and then modifies the data source of my tables to be the new range.

I want to disconnect the slicers from the tables, update the table, update the data source for the tables, and then reconnect the slicers to the tables.

In the last stage; after removing the slicers and updating the ranges in VBA, I find myself unable to reattach the slicers to the tables. I am able to do it manually by right clicking on the slicer -> 'PivotTable Connections' and checking all the boxes.

I recorded a macro of this.

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("dryer_table"))
 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("operating_table"))
 ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_Shift").PivotTables.AddPivotTable ( _
        ActiveSheet.PivotTables("shift_table"))
```

It is Throwing the error:

> Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PivotTables property of the
>   Worksheet class

My slicer is named 'Slicer_Shift', and the table names are correct.

Using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got it working. I fixed it by changing `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets(<name>)`.